# read excel put values in xml

Tags: java, xml, excel, xpath

I have an empty request xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org
/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://MessageView/">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
  <mes:abcRq>
     <RqID>?</RqID>
     <MsgRqHdr>
        <ARqID>?</ARqID>
        <SRole>?</SRole>
        <SSession>?</SSession>
        <IP>?</IP>
        <PTy>?</PTy>
        <TID>?</TID>
        <TDt>?</TDt>
        <TSsDt>?</TSsDt>
        <IP>?</IP>
        <TPId>?</TPId>
        <LP>?</LP>
        <MxRLim>?</MxRLim>
        <CRLt>?</CRLt>
        <IP>?</IP>
        <PTy>?</PTy>
     </MsgRqHdr>
  </mes:abcRq>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For this xml i  have calculated the xpath of elements :-

```
RqID    RqID[1]
ARqID   MsgRqHdr[1]/ARqID[1]
SRole   MsgRqHdr[1]/SRole[1]
SSession    MsgRqHdr[1]/SSession[1]
IP  MsgRqHdr[1]/IP[1]
PTy MsgRqHdr[1]/PTy[1]
TID MsgRqHdr[1]/TID[1]
TDt MsgRqHdr[1]/TDt[1]
TSsDt   MsgRqHdr[1]/TSsDt[1]
IP_1    MsgRqHdr[1]/IP[2]
TPId    MsgRqHdr[1]/TPId[1]
LP  MsgRqHdr[1]/LP[1]
MxRLim  MsgRqHdr[1]/MxRLim[1]
CRLt    MsgRqHdr[1]/CRLt[1]
IP_2    MsgRqHdr[1]/IP[3]
Pty_1   MsgRqHdr[1]/PTy[2]
```

Now i have another sheet called the Test data sheet, i put values of as according to my Test case in there , ex:-

```
TestDataID  RunTestForData  TestRequestRequired RqID    ARqID   SRole   SSession    IP  Pty TID TDt TSsDt   IP_1    TPId    LP  MxRLim  CRLt    IP_2    PTy_1
1.1.1   Yes Yes                         3               01  Top     99      NnECn
1.1.2   Yes Yes                         2               02  Top     100     ECn
```

Now , Is there a way i can read the values of test data excel and put it in the xml somehow ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all create bean class and put all values that you want to insert into xml

there are some api already provided for reading excel and storing values in custome object

please look into below link : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-excel-files-in-java-example/

after storing all values from excel to object then used Dom parser to insert values from object to XML file.

you can get node from current xml and put values using setTextContent() of node object.

hope i will help you.

Comment: #Tipu Sultan , the thing is that this is a sample xml , once in runtime there could be an xml with 2000 fields , would creating a beans class work then .?

Comment: ohh...okay. but most of the fields are repeated right?

Comment: They can be , if you refer to the second excel that i have added in the question, it has 2 fields, one is property and the other is xpath , the property column might have redundant fields, which i have named as "_1", "_2" and so on., i have written the code till i find redundant fields and have named it "_i" in my code, but now i have to take the values inserted in the Test Data sheet(3rd  Excel) and put it in the xml at the right place (i guess that has to maped in accordance to the xpath).

Comment: can anyone help me on this .?